# mdns works different on snow leopard and lion

Tags: macos, network, bonjour

I have a few linux machines on my local network. Using avahi, they expose their name over mdns. This enables me to access them by doing `ping green.local` or other commands (but by using the hostname).

To simplify using them, I added `local` to the search path for my network settings. That is... *System Preferences > Network > Ethernet > Advanced > DNS > Search Domains*.

When I was running snow leopard, this enabled me to do either: `ping green.local` or `ping green`.

However, now that I'm running lion, I get the following result:

```
[9:12pm][wlynch@orange ~] ping green
ping: cannot resolve green: Unknown host

[9:12pm][wlynch@orange ~] ping green.local.
PING green.local (192.168.1.147): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.1.147: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.106 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.147: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.165 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.147: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.141 ms
^C
--- green.local ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.106/0.137/0.165/0.024 ms

[9:12pm][wlynch@orange ~] ping green
PING green.local (192.168.1.147): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.1.147: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.117 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.147: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.147 ms
^C
--- green.local ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.117/0.132/0.147/0.015 ms
```

To summarize, I'm not able to access the server as the name `green` until I've accessed it as `green.local`. Once I've done that, it works for some amount of time (I've never figured out exactly how long, something less than a day).

As an aside, I've looked at my network traffic when I do hostname lookups of `green` and `green.local`. When I request `green`, I do not see a mdns request. I do however see one when I do a lookup of `green.local`.

Is there any way to revert to how snow leopard functioned in this regard?

Comment: Hmm - I've had that work reliably with several non mac servers - have you double checked the locations to be sure you're configuring the active one?

Comment: @bmike: Sorry, I'm not following what you're asking. As I mentioned in the post. This setup worked with snow leopard, it's only with lion that I'm having problems.

Comment: I know - is search .local showing in your /etc/resolv.conf - sometimes when I plug info into the preference pane, it's for another network location or the wrong adapter.

Comment: @bmike: Yes. It is there.